# How to represent a Towers of Hanoi problem using a graph?

Tags: algorithm, graph, towers-of-hanoi

I am not able to figure out how the graphs shown [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_of_Hanoi) are constructed?

For example, what does this graph represent?

[image]
<sub>(source: [wikimedia.org](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d9/Tower_of_Hanoi-2.svg/255px-Tower_of_Hanoi-2.svg.png))</sub>

"`Nodes are distribution of discs`", but I will only have one disc of size `a`. So, what does node `aa` represent?

I know the answer would be simple, but I cannot figure it out at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`a`, `b` and `c` are the three pegs. So `aa` means that the two discs are on peg `a`.